# Why can't rust infer types specified after arithmetic operators?

Tags: rust

Can anyone tell me why code 1 works but code2 doesn't?

### code 1

```rs
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => {num},
            Err(e) => {println!("{}",e);0},
        };
```

### code 2

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => {num * 2},
            Err(e) => {println!("{}",e);0},
        };
```

#### error

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:18:16
   |
18 |             Ok(num) => {num * 2},
   |                ^^^ cannot infer type
   |
help: consider specifying the type argument in the method call
   |
17 |         let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse::<F>() {
   |                                                  +++++
```

Comment: Rust never infers types defined past basic math operators, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` etc. Even if in this case there would be only 1 option there could potentially be multiple definitions for these operators depending on the type.

Comment: @mousetail _Rust never infers types defined past basic math operators, +, -, *, / etc._ this statement might be a little bit confusing, because it can -> ([sample](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=93479f1ee0c0fbfb9a2f524d2546c282)). It might be correct for `std` implementations though, because there is multiple implementations `Mul` for `u32` [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html#impl-Mul%3Cu32%3E), and compiler cannot figure , it should be parsed for `&u32` or `u32` or something else.

Comment: @ÖmerErden in your code sample you specify the type in between the arithmetic operator and the type inference. Rust only can't figure it out if there is a arithmetic operator *and no other hints* between a place where the type needs to be inferred and where it is specified.

Comment: @mousetail On a type specifying basis I don't see any differences between [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=23728eb84158c9a6f6c20a28c6fd4323) and my sample. Here is the problem reproduced with introducing another implementation to my [sample](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14db2c7442cd63d9ee0cda34709931dd)

Comment: You are correct. Seems the order of the operations in the `+` operator matters

Answer (score 1):

You could create a ambiguous type easily in this way. The `Result` of a operator is not unique. Consider if this existed somewhere in your code.

```rs
struct A;

// Allow this struct to be used in Parse
impl FromStr for A {
    ... // implementation of FromStr
}

// Allow this struct to be used in add
impl Add<u32> for A {
    type Output = u32;

    // implementation of Add
}

fn main() {
    let k:u32 = "".parse().unwrap() + 5
}
```

What variant of `parse` should be used? `u32` or `A`? There is no way to tell, both would be valid. `A` could be defined in some external crate and thus modify code based on a situation that's hard to control.

For this reason, rust can't infer types past operators.

You can easily clarify the variant used with the turbofish (`::<>`) operator:

```
fn main() {
    let k:u32 = "".parse::<u32>().unwrap() + 5
}
```